# Invisible htaccess Redirect keep being visible Problem

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, lamp

I have numerous addon domains and subdomains in a cPanel account.

My main domain is `example1.com` and the various subdomains are of the type:

```
sub1.example1.com
sub2.example1.com
example2.com
sub3.example2.com
.
.
.
```

The content i have in my main domain is in the form:
 `example1.com/story/dynamicStoryId`
 `example1.com/blog/dynamicBlogId` 
`example1.com/*/*`

Through the htaccess file, i want to make invisible redirects on all the sub/addon domains so that the concept is

```
User Input URL               | Content URL             | Browser URL
sub1.example1.com/story/1234 | example1.com/story/1234 | sub1.example1.com/story/1234
example2.com/blog/4321       | example1.com/blog/4321  | example2.com/blog/4321
sub3.example2.com/*/*        | example1.com/*/*        | sub3.example2.com/*/*
```

What i have tried so far:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
.
.
#the actual problem
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example1.com/$1 [L,NE,P]
</IfModule>
```

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
.
.
#the actual problem
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example1.com/$1 [P]
</IfModule>
```

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
.
.
#the actual problem
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.example1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example1.com/$1 [P]
</IfModule>
```

On all the above examples, the redirect is kept visible every time.

The procedure works fine but when i go to `sub1.example1.com/story/1234` i get a 302 redirect to `example1.com/story/1234`

I have really searched half google and stack overflow and still not found anything helpfull!

.htaccess,regex etc is not my strong point so the solution may be fairly obvious but i still can not figure things out!

Comment: Are all these subdomains pointing to the same document root/server as your main domain?

Comment: of course all of them have A records pointing to the server. They are all under the same cPanel account with one being the main. I have a directory inside the `public_html` which contains all the other domains. I want to contain just an .htaccess file with an invisible redirect on those

Comment: If this is all going into the same document root to begin with, then you should not need to proxy those requests, just redirecting to the correct directory internally should do …?

Comment: Hmm. I understand what you propose but how can this be done invisibly?
The structure is
`public_html` contains frontend aspect of the site, inside there is a folder `cd` with the Custom Domains